# Ironsource Real Ads Not Showing

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ads, mobile-ad-mediation, ironsource

I am working on a game in unity and trying to integrate ironsource in the game for ads,
after initializing with test app key test app seen in android

```
IronSource.Agent.init(appKeyTest);
```

But after initializing with real app key ads are not working in android

```
IronSource.Agent.init(appKey);
```

*Also added the respective appKeys in ironsource developer setting in unity editor. *

**One more thing our game is already uploaded on playstore just changing its ads network. **

Solution on integrating ironsource with real appkeys

Comment: You want real ads in debug?

Comment: I want ads using real ids, already enable test mode in ironsource dashboard